# Multiline grid with elements of same height using flexbox

Tags: css, grid, height, flexbox

I'm trying to create a grid which will have multiple row and columns. I'd like them all to have the same height using flexbox, but the only thing I can get is columns of same size on one row.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do: http://jsbin.com/maxavahesa/1/edit?html,css,output

In this example I'd like all my `<li>`'s to have the same height, which means the height of the biggest item (in my example, this would be the last `<li>`). Is it possible to achieve with flexbox ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more how that grid should work? Will the content vary in each box? Is there always only one item with much more content? Is it OK to give the `ul` a fixed height?  Your example is extremely reduced so that just saying "no, it's not possible is true but not helpful".

Comment: I'd like all my elements to have the same height (which means the height of the biggest one of them), no matter what content is used.

Comment: [You expect the boxes to have the same height as the highest box even if the viewport is smaller?](https://i.imgur.com/sg4F5aJ.png).

Comment: To be honest, I don't really care about the viewport. My only wish is that all `<li>` have the same height, even if they're not on the same line. I know it's easily achievable with JS, but I was wondering if flexbox could provide a solution too.

Comment: Also worth noting: I don't want to resort to `min-height` for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not possible with pure CSS/flexbox.

I'll cite the W3C spec:

> When a flex container has multiple lines, the cross size of each line **is the minimum size necessary to contain the flex items on the line** (after aligment due to align-self), and the lines are aligned within the flex container with the align-content property. [...]

(From http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-lines)

So, one item is only expanded to the maximum height of that line it's currently on.

Terminology of the above quote:

[image]

(From http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#box-model)

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll just stick to my JS solution then.

Answer (score 0):

Although this topic is old, for anyone seeing this topic now, you can't achieve that with flexbox, like it's said in the accepted answer; however, you can achive that with [Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;  
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 1px;
  grid-row-gap: 1px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: grey;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <li>d</li>
  <li>e</li>
  <li>f</li>
  <li>g</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum et rerum labore repellat voluptatibus ut sit deserunt facilis dolorum exercitationem earum quibusdam quo itaque distinctio magnam, accusantium soluta voluptates aut.</li>
</ul>
```

Although this is not flexbox, it behaves in a very similar way and it's very easy to use.

This doesn't force the list items to have a specific display, so the items could be `block`, `flex`, `inline-block` (like in the example above).

Just define the list (container) with:

1. `display: grid` (will use the grid layout);
2. `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr)` (assuming you want 4 columns per row);
3. `grid-auto-rows: 1fr` (`fr` is the flex factor, the value of 1 meaning the max size of all items in the list; more information in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-rows).