# Flex Items same height across rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, panel

I'm developing bootstrap panels using angularjs and am wondering if it's possible to have all the panels (in all rows) be the same height using flex boxes.  Currently the panels are the same height if they're in the same row, but am wondering if that can be applied across all rows.

Comment: Can you provide some code? I think I understand your question, but would like you to give some more concrete info.

Comment: No way (Without Javascript). More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27600059/multiline-grid-with-elements-of-same-height-using-flexbox